# Thunderbird 115.8.1 (64-bit) using CC as identity

Tags: thunderbird

When I choose 'reply all', instead of using one of my identities, Thunderbird moves the first address in the CC field to the 'from' field. Has anybody encountered this bug as well?

[image: Example of the bug's occurrence]

- Thunderbird version: 115.8.1 (64-bit)
- I have disabled all add-ons to make sure they are not the reason

Comment: When doing "Reply to All", is your e-mail address in the e-mail you are replying to the same as configured in the account? ([link](https://superuser.com/questions/120241/thunderbird-3-reply-to-all-also-replies-to-myself)) Is "Reply-to Address" set in the account Settings?

Comment: The emails are not destined to me, they are sent to another account ex.: client@mycompany.com. Every e-mail sent to that address is forwarded to me. Each of my identities has a Reply-to set. Ex.: A Ccient sends e-mail to client@mycompany.com which is then automatically forwarded to me. I answer with my personal email, with reply-to set to client@mycompany.com. This is so the client has the impression he is corresponding with the company and not a specific person. The email in the reply-to is always in the CC as well, because that's how the client sends it.

Comment: The bug usually occurs when there are more than 2 addresses in the CC

Comment: This is either a bug which should be reported to the TB team, or there is some address entities mismatch.

Comment: I think it's a bug. I'm trying to find the specific set of steps to reproduce. As far as I can tell, the bug occurs in the following scenario: Someone sends an e-mail to one of my identities, and said identity is the first recipient of the message (having more than one recipient). Then thunderbird gives me the identity of the second person in the 'To'/'CC' field, removing that address from its original place.